# Do experiments of proton radius measure it to be larger at higher speeds?

Tags: particle-physics, protons

Do the experiments conducted to measure the proton radius consistently measure it to be larger when the proton has higher momentum?

Answer (score 2):

The proton radius is deduced from experiments that fit the data with specific theoretical models , from which the charge radius of the proton can be deduced for a specific interaction.

There has been ongoing [research on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_radius_puzzle) , and for all the different  methods and experimental layouts there is one sure point, they all use the mathematics of quantum physics and special relativity. In special relativity  the  mass you are inquiring about, is irrelevant. The particle has an [invariant mass](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) and that is what all  high energy physics experiments use . Relativistic mass , the one you are asking about, depends on the observer, and experiments use, in the calculations to fit the data , invariant quantities. Maybe [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity) will help in clearing the concepts for you.